# Convex downward function and its inverse function

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

How to prove that if function $f$ is convex downward and invertible then $f^{-1}$ is convex downward or convex upward? When is it downward and when upward?

Comment: For the benefit of other readers: "convex downward" -> "concave", and "convex upward" -> "convex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g$ be the inverse function of $f$. That is , $g=f^{-1}$.

Then, $$f(g(x))=x$$
Differentiating, $$f'(g(x)).g'(x)=1$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$$
Differentiating again, $$g''(x)=\frac{-1}{\left(f'(g(x))\right)^2}.f''(g(x)).g'(x)$$

Substituting the value of $g'(x)$ obtained earlier,
$$g''(x)=\frac{-f''(g(x))}{(f'(g(x)))^3}$$

You can draw your conclusions from here now.

Comment: According to this, the inverse of a convex decreasing function should be convex. But this is not so for -x^3